# Get the exact path of mounted memory card, but not external phone memory

Tags: java, android

Could anyone advise how to get the exact path of memory card. because when i use environment.getExternalStorageDirectory, it gives me the path of the external SD Card of the phone (which is the second storage of the phone).

so please advise how can i get exact path of the inserted memory card

Comment: What would be the difference between an _"inserted memory card"_ and an _"external SD card"_?

Comment: most of the new android devices contain two internal phone memories, first one is known as internal phone memory that can be reached by (Environment.getInternalStorageDirectory), and the second is knows as external phone memory that can be reached by (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory). the problem now is if i inserted a third storage (external memory card), what is the code i can use to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get path like this
`String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code for xamarin.forms

```
string Path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
```